# Getting "Unable to create directory" error in Maven JAXB plugin, but only once

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

In my Maven build, I use the `jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.2` to generate classes from an XML schema file. These are the only Java files in the project, i.e. there are no non-generated Java files.

When I run `mvn compile` with a clean project, I run into the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.2:xjc (xjc) on project awap: Unable to create directory D:\myproject\target\classes\ -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.2:xjc (xjc) on project awap: Unable to create directory D:\myproject\target\classes\
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to create directory D:\myproject\target\classes\
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.javageneration.AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.performExecution(AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.java:482)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractJaxbMojo.execute(AbstractJaxbMojo.java:257)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to create directory D:\myproject\target\classes\
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.forceMkdir(FileUtils.java:1615)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.javageneration.AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.performExecution(AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.java:439)
    ... 24 more
```

**But** after running this, the `target/classes` directory actually does exist! And indeed, if I attempt `mvn compile` a second time (without cleaning in between), the build succeeds.

The same error occurs with the most recent plugin version 2.4.

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/sonatype/plexus-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/util/FileUtils.java#L1620) of the function that throws the exception, I see that `File.mkdirs()` is called. Why this returns `false`, I don't know. After all, the directory does get created at some point...

Why does this happen and how can I make my build succeed the first time around?

Answer (score 1):

So I could indirectly solve this. I had marked the (nonstandard) directory to which the classes were generated as a source directory in maven.

I changed this so the classes get generated into the default `target/generated-sources` and removed the extra source folder. This made the error go away.